# JQuery each function?

Tags: jquery

Script:

```
var degress = GiveDegrees();

$(function () {
    //alert(GiveDegrees());  //output: 89,91,87,90,91
});

function GiveDegrees() {
    var divs = $('p.wx-temp');
    var degrees = new Array();

    $.each(divs, function (i, j) {
        degrees.push(stringToNum($(this).text()));
    });

    return degrees;
}

function stringToNum(str) {
    return str.match(/\d+/g);
}
```

I have this :

```
$("p.wx-temp").each(degress, function (index) {
    $(this).append(degress[index], "<sup>°C</sup>");

    alert("I works");
});
```

But It does not work. when I write like this:

```
$("p.wx-temp").each(function (index) {
    $(this).append("<sup>°C</sup>");

    alert("I works");
});
```

It works. Is there no overload method for `.each()` function `.each(data, function (index))` ?

degrees array is integer array that include five int as `89,91,87,90,91`. How can I use `.each` function to add array values to each `p` element.

Thanks.

Comment: `{89,91,87,90,91}` is not a valid object.

Comment: its array of integer. It is only displaying not real format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you need to bring `degress` into the `each` at all? It’s already available, using closures:

```
$("p.wx-temp").each(function(index) {
    $(this).append(degrees[index], "<sup>°C</sup>");
    alert("I works");
});
```

OR

```
var $elems = $("p.wx-temp");
$.each(degrees, function(i, val) {
    $elems.eq(i).append(val, '<sup>°C</sup>');
});
```

If the elements length matches the array length, it should make no difference wich one you loop, but the first one is probably faster (although using a native array loop would be fastest).

Note that you are spelling `degrees` and `degress` differently in the two sections.

Comment: This is solution.Thanks It still does not work for me :(( I thinks there is another problem. When I write with alert degress[0] out of each function it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
var degrees = [89,91,87,90,91];
$("p.wx-temp").each( function (index) {
    $(this).append(degrees[index], "<sup>°C</sup>");

    alert("I work");
});
```